# Dar salto de linea automático al ingresar datos a un CSV en C

Tags: c

en una función se piden datos de un nuevo alumno con cierto formato y estos se guardan en el csv de manera correcta el problema es que al ingresar mas de un alumno los datos los escribe sobre la misma linea y no da un salto de linea:

los datos se piden en el siguiente formato:

**boleta,nombre,apllidos,edad,correo,grupo**

y se guardan en el csv de manera correcta, el problema es que al ingresar a otro alumno por ejemplo 2 alumnos pasa esto:

**boleta1 nombre1 apllidos1 edad1 correo1 grupo1boleta2 nombre2 apllidos2 edad2 correo2 grupo2**

y necesito esto:

- **boleta1 nombre1 apllidos1 edad1 correo1 grupo1**
- **boleta2 nombre2 apllidos2 edad2 correo2 grupo2**

este es el código de la función

```
//2) Funcion Insertar
void fuins(){

    char opreboot[5]={};

    char c;

    do
    {
        FILE*lista_alumnos;
        lista_alumnos=fopen("lista_alumnos.csv","a+t");

        system("cls");

        printf("Insertar alumno a la lista del grupo 1CV2\n\n\n\n");
        printf("\nIngresar datos de alumno en el siguiente formato:\n\nboleta,nombre,apllidos,edad,correo,grupo\n\nTerminal> ");
        scanf("%c",&c);

        while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        {
             printf("%c",fputc(c,lista_alumnos));
        }

        fclose ( lista_alumnos );

        printf("\n\nDesea agregar otro alumno? (s/n)\n\nTerminal> ");
        scanf("%s",&opreboot);
    }
    while(strcmp(opreboot,"s")==0);
    return;
    }
```

si alguien pudiera ayudarme, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Podrías añadir el `\n` justo después del `while`, ¿funcionaría eso?

Comment: me parece que nunca esta limpiando c, y de ahi el problema...

Comment: Tal como dice @AlvaroMontoro, hace un `fputc('\n', lista_alumnos);` justo despues del `while`, antes del `fclose(lista_alumnos)`.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tienes razón y gracias NaCl siempre respondiendo :D sin duda tengo que estudiar mas.

Comment: @CarlosDayan yo no lo añadí como respuesta porque no estaba en un ordenador donde probarlo. Si lo has probado y funciona, deberías ponerlo como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías añadir un `\n` justo después del `while` que escribe los caracteres en el documento. De ese modo se incluirá un salto de línea en el fichero CSV también.

Algo como esto (sólo el código relevante, con lo que [sugirió NaCl en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67164/dar-salto-de-linea-autom%C3%A1tico-al-ingresar-datos-a-un-csv-en-c#comment122838_67164)):

```
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
         printf("%c",fputc(c,lista_alumnos));
    }

    fputc('\n', lista_alumnos);

    fclose ( lista_alumnos );
```